# How to detect the watermark in image using Google Cloud vision

Tags: artificial-intelligence, watermark, google-vision

How to detect the watermark in image using Google vision API?
I am using the Gooogle collab and want to detect the watermark in image using Google vision API?

Can you provide me the sample of code any repo or docs where it is already done?